# R async library to parallelise long-running web requests

Tags: r, asynchronous

I need to iterate through a list of around 100 s3 buckets checking whether I have access, using a function called `check_access`.  Each call is long-running,  so doing this in a loop takes too long.  The majority of the time is waiting for the web request to come back.

I am trying to use the [`async`](https://github.com/r-lib/async) library to make this faster.

My initial failed attempt looked something like this:

```
# buckets is a vector of bucket names

afun <- async(function(buckets) {

  check_access_async <- async(function(bucket_name) {
    aws.s3::bucket_exists(bucket_name)[1]
  })

  r1 <- check_access_async(buckets[1])
  r2 <- check_access_async(buckets[2])
  await_all(r1,r2)
})

system.time(result <- synchronise(afun(buckets)))
```

Checking execution time with  `system.time` suggested that the above code does not actually parallelise anything - so I started looking in the docs at the implementation of the async [http functions](https://github.com/r-lib/async/blob/master/R/http.R%60).

This suggested I need to create a deferred function in order to get the benefits of parallelisation.  Here is my current attempt, but it still doesn't work:

```
afun2 <- async(function(buckets) {

  mydeferred1 <- async::deferred$new(function(resolve, reject) {
    hasaccess <- aws.s3::bucket_exists(buckets[1])[1]
    resolve(hasaccess)
  })

  mydeferred2 <- async::deferred$new(function(resolve, reject) {
    hasaccess <- aws.s3::bucket_exists(buckets[2])[1]
    resolve(hasaccess)
  })

  await_all(mydeferred1, mydeferred2)
})

system.time(synchronise(afun2(buckets)))
```

Obviously once I get this working I'll write everything into loops/apply statements. For the moment I'm just trying to figure out the correct usage of 'deferred'.

I'd be very grateful for advice on how to use the library properly.

p.s. I have also tried to use `parallel` to solve this problem.  I got it working, but the delay in starting threads meant it didn't save as much time as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. You would need sync http queries, and `aws.s3` does not use those.